# How can I process my own custom binary file in Windows 7?

Tags: .net

I have a .NET application called processor.exe - I have it setup so that if a user double clicks on file.myfile (the extension for my custom file is *.myfile) the file gets processed by processor.exe.

As it turns out, file.myfile gets passed to processor.exe as the first argument. So all I can do is just pass the contents of file.myfile to processor.exe.

Instead, I would like to be able to process it as it's own file. so I can add switches and parameters to it.

processor.exe is going to be a custom scripting system. and *.myfile is the file extension for the scripts it runs.

Everyone know, that Java and .NET binaries run like that. I would like to do the same thing, except I'm creating more of a binary scripting system. For now I just want it to process text lines, but I want to be able to run them with parameters.

How can I set this up?

I am using C# and VB.NET to create this. Any help would be great!

Update:

I create a small application called processor.exe If you double click it, it does nothing. So I setup a file association in Windows 7 for *.myfile files. When double clicking a *.myfile it runs processor.exe which as I said does nothing. However, processor.exe takes the data which is text lines from *.myfile and reads it into an array of strings. So now processor.exe is ready to run the text lines as a script. Simple enough and it works. However, I would like to extend this. I would like to be able to edit the *.myfile properties and change it for example to this -> "script.myfile /test". Notice I added the /test switch. So from now on when the user double clicks script.myfile, ... it will run the script in a not yet written test mode. You know of course, you can't do that to non executable files. Windows 7 does not let you change the properties and why should it, since it runs a binary (processor.exe) which can have it's own switches. So basically I would like to know, how a system like .NET or Java creates binaries, so I can setup my own! For now my scripts are text based, but I'm learning more in depth language lessons and shortly, I will want to change this to be a binary format. So script.myfile will be a binary file like a *.exe. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "process it as its own file"? It's not really clear what you mean. How would you add switches and parameters if you're just double-clicking on the file?

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of "immediately drop into code" although a short but complete program would help. To me, the problem is that it's not really clear what you mean - the "so I can add switches and parameters to it" is particularly vague.

Comment: All of this should be in the *question*, not in comments. Please edit your question.

Comment: This sounds like a file association question. Are you asking how to make *.myfile open with processor.exe including additional parameters?

Comment: Command line switches are just one way to 'communicate' processing options to a program.  Why not embed the same (optional) details in 'somescript.myfile' and read/process them from there?

Comment: This is a file association question. I imagine that your association currently looks like %1. You want to use *% to your file association so all args are passed through. This question should be migrated to superuser.